# Debugging Scala Services In Intellij

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug a series of services that I have written using scala and the play framework. I can see the errors in the browser but now I want to see the values of the variables at breakpoints. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in much the same was as java. Start up your play service in debug mode

```
play debug run
```

Then add a run/debug configuration, setting the type to remote configuration, specifying the host/port that you're connecting to (localhost if you're running intellij on the same box, port defaults to 9999).

Then click the debug button and you should connect to your play service. Drop breakpoints in an inspect as normal.

Comment: So you have to press debug in intellij for it to actually attach and debug?

Comment: The answer to my above comment is yes. Other good resources for this are http://digitalsanctum.com/2012/05/26/play-framework-2-tutorial-debugging-with-intellij-idea/ and http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/IDE